# How Can I draw a Svg with two semicirlces having different colours and apply animations to it

Tags: css, svg

I am able to make this using css by simply applying styles to  a div and applying keyframes for animation
the code looks something like this

```css
.loader {
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  border-right: 0.75em solid #E0E3E9;
  border-bottom: 0.75em solid #E0E3E9;
  border-left: 0.75em solid #6B04A8;
  border-top: 0.75em solid #6B04A8;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
  animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

}

@-webkit-keyframes load8 {
  0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes load8 {
  0% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

  100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

so basically applied a two sets of border colours and a border-radius of 50% to make it look like a circle and applied transform on it.
I need to do the same in a svg , can someone point me in the right direction from where to start , thanks in advance

Comment: you can find the working example in the codepen below  https://codepen.io/tarunjamana/pen/ExPNVve

Comment: [Spinkit](https://github.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit) Here is a collection of loading icon It possibly what you need. In case you still wanna have a loading svg you can draw svg by using Figma or Adobe XD then add css animation to the loader [Animating svg css](https://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I'm using 2 circles one over another. The first one (the base) has a silver stroke. The second one has a purple stroke and `stroke-dasharray = "125.5"` meaning that there are strokes of 125.5 and gaps the same size. Also 125.5 represents half total length of the circumference.

The center of the circle is in the origin of the svg canvas (0,0) Please observe the viewBox of the svg element: x:-50 y:-50 width:100 height:100

```css
svg{width:50px;display:block; margin:0 auto;}

#theCircle{animation: load8 1s linear infinite;}

@keyframes load8 {
to {
    transform: rotate(-1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100"> 
   <circle  r="40" fill="none" stroke="silver" stroke-width="10" />
  <circle id="theCircle" r="40" fill="none" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray = "125.5" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks for your input it helped me develop a  new variation of the above loader but not getting the animations right could you please check the link below and guide me . Thanks in advance  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527385/how-to-animate-a-svg-loader-such-that-it-grows-and-shrinks-at-certain-points-of)