# How to animate a svg loader such that It grows and shrinks at certain points of the circle?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: Svg loader]

the required loader is to be of the following gif given above but needs  to be implemented in a svg.
the code given below is the svg I have implemented so far but I am not able to get the required animation as that of a gif. Can somebody point out where I am going wrong or help me with how to get the animations right. Thanks in advance

```css
svg{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  
}

/* .circles{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
} */



#inner{
  stroke-dasharray: 314 314;
  stroke-dashoffset: 314;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  /* animation: rotate 2s linear infinite; */
  animation: animate 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{

  0%,100%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  }
  
  50%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  50.1%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 628 ;
  }

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="svg.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg>

    <g class="circles">
      <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="none"  stroke-width="15px" stroke="#E0E3E9">
         </circle>
      <circle id="inner" cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="none"  stroke-width="12px" stroke="#6B04A8">
         </circle>
    </g>
     
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need: instead of animating the stroke-dashoffset I'm animating the stroke-dasharray

```css
svg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

/* .circles{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
} */

#inner {
  stroke-dasharray: 1 314;
  stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  /* animation: rotate 2s linear infinite; */
  animation: animate 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 314;
  }
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
 <svg>
   <g class="circles">
     <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="none" stroke-width="15px" stroke="#E0E3E9">
     </circle>
     <circle id="inner" cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="none" stroke-width="12px" stroke="#6B04A8">
     </circle>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

#### Second attempt:

The OP is commenting

> for the first 50% of the circle it has to grow and after crossing the 50% only it should shrink

```css
svg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

/* .circles{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
} */

#inner {
 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: animate 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{

  0%{
    stroke-dasharray: 0 314;
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  }
  
  50%{
    stroke-dasharray: 157 157;
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  }

  75%{
    stroke-dasharray: 157 157;
    stroke-dashoffset: 157;
  }

  
  100%{
    stroke-dasharray: 0 314;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}


svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg>
   <g class="circles">
     <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="none" stroke-width="15px" stroke="#E0E3E9">
     </circle>
     <circle id="inner" cx="125" cy="125" r="50" fill="none" stroke-width="12px" stroke="#6B04A8" stroke-dasharray="0 314" stroke-dashoffset = "157">
     </circle>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: for the first 50% of the circle it has to grow and after crossing the 50% only it should shrink as seen in the gif given above , can you suggest how to animate that

Comment: I think the animation will definitely not work in IE11 any workaround on your mind to make it work